# build failed with error Error:Execution failed for task

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I try build the app but I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':GenraMovil:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 
'C:\Users\tdisa\Appdata\local\Android\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

And I try other options of similar topics and doesn't work

this is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
    multiDexEnabled true
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
compile files('libs/ksoap2-extra-ntlm-3.0.0-RC.1.jar')
compile files('libs/jcifs-1.3.14.jar')
}
```

this is the link of picture android structure of my project:

[android structure of my project:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqqCk.png)

this is the link of picture project structure:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDZ4z.png)

help me solve the problem please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your following line not completed by the version number
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'`

I faced this problem and solved by remove compile
 `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1`

and let it like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-beta1'
}
```

another suggestion if you want to keep it upgrade your
`buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"`

Comment: thanks , the problem was in the buildToolsVersion , I change the version and it worked